# How can I create a CSV and save it to the host in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have the logic to create a CSV and serve it as a download to the user, but what I am wanting to do is automatically create the CSV once a week during off hours and upload it to S3 and serve it from there. The hope is to drastically decrease the download time for the user since the CSV takes a couple minutes to generate.

The only step I'm missing is how I can go about saving this CSV to the host. What I plan on doing is saving it to the host, upload it to S3, and then deleting it from the host.

Any ideas how I can go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I have a CSV that I generate when a user clicks a download button with data from ActiveRecord. This is served to the user after the CSV is built. I'm not sure how to capture this CSV and save it locally instead of downloading the file to the user's browser. Does that help?

Comment: do you want to save the file or rails server or s3? saving your file on the server hosting rails app is not recommended as it might take up all the free storage on the server. what is the use case here can you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create and save CSV in your host server like this.

```
CSV.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'csv_cache', "#{csv_name}"), "wb") do |csv|
# your logic
end
```

This will create a CSV in the `tmp/csv_cache` folder with the name specified in csv_name.

Then you can upload this into the s3 like this

```
file_url = Utils.new().upload_to_s3(csv_name, Rails.root.join('tmp', 'csv_cache', csv_name))

class Utils
 def upload_to_s3(file_name, source)
    obj = AMAZON_S3_CLIENT.bucket(S3_BUCKET).object('csv_cache/'+file_name)
    obj.upload_file source, {acl: 'public-read'}
    return obj.public_url
  end
end
```

Then you can delete the file from the server.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple bash script on your server:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Save this file to /home/user/upload.sh

curl -o /tmp/csv_file.csv http://localhost/path/to/csv
aws s3 mv /tmp/csv_file.csv s3://bucket/
```

And then schedule the script via cron

```
# /etc/crontab

# Run every day at 08.15
15 08 * * * user /home/user/upload.sh
```

Note: `http://localhost/path/to/csv` would be the same url your button links to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sidekiq or cron that will run your CSV-task(job) weekly. Within this task, CSV is saved to the host using 'CSV.open' and after that upload to S3.

You might need a table to store the S3 path of the file. Or I guess you can just overwrite the old file and reuse the S3 path.